# stop for execution javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Well, I'm trying to get him to make some fields, if any of them is equal, it's the message and, though my message is giving non-stop, direct, how can I make it stop giving a lot of alert?

```
function sendAll(){
      for (i = 1;i <=10;i ++) {
         for (o = 1;o <=10;o ++) {
             if(document.getElementById("table" + i).value==document.getElementById("table" + o).value){
                 alert("Some field is equal, check again.");
                 break;
                 return false;
             }
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: Remove the `break`: that makes it break from the *inner* loop (the outer loop will keep looping) before the `return` is executed.

Comment: I am just glad someone understood the queston

Comment: @Huangism I'm only 50%, hence a mere comment ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) statement, just remove it. [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) statement will do the rest

use

```
function sendAll() {
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        for (o = 1; o <= 10; o++) {
            if (document.getElementById("table" + i).value == document.getElementById("table" + o).value) {
                alert("Some field is equal, check again.");
                //break;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    //If you are using for validation purpose return true
    // as default
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Best add a `return true;` after the outer loop completes or the function will return `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

Your [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) simply stops the inner-most loop, but allows the outer loop to continue. To break out of the function entirely, just use a [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return):

```
function sendAll(){
      for (i = 1;i <=10;i ++) {
         for (o = 1;o <=10;o ++) {
             if(document.getElementById("table" + i).value==document.getElementById("table" + o).value){
                 alert("Some field is equal, check again.");
                 return false;
             }
          }
      }

      return true; // suggested by Mike W
}
```

Comment: Best add a `return true;` after the outer loop completes or the function will return `undefined`

Comment: @MikeW Good point. It's also possible OP is not actually be using the return value at all, in case `return false;` should be `return;`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
function sendAll(){
var bEqual = false;
  for (i = 1;i <=10;i ++) {
     for (o = 1;o <=10;o ++) {
         if(document.getElementById("table" + i).value==document.getElementById("table" + o).value){
             bEqual = true;
         }
      }
  }
if (bEqual) {
    alert("Some field is equal, check again.");
}
return bEqual;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could do:

```
function sendAll(){
     if (!fieldsOk()) {
         alert('some message');
     } 
}

function fieldsOk() {
    for (i = 1;i <=10;i ++) {
         for (o = 1;o <=10;o ++) {
             if(document.getElementById("table" + i).value==document.getElementById("table" + o).value){
                 return false;
             }
          }
    }
    return true;
}
```